# ASP.Net MVC - Run background process/ async without waiting in foreground

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, background-process

I have a requirement where I should run a background process/thread in .Net MVC application, which will be async and doesn't wait for the action in the foreground/ UI.

In ASP.Net core app there is  **Coravel.Queuing.Interfaces** available which will take care of the background process using IQueue.

Is there anything similar to it in .Net MVC for the same ? I have googled but found no relevant answer.

Below is the code used in ASP.Net Core using Corovel for queing and background process

```
using Coravel.Queuing.Interfaces;

 IQueue queue;
         
 _queue.QueueAsyncTask(() => method1()); 

private async Task method1()
        {
            await Task.FromResult(ActualMethod()); --- here ActualMethod() will execute from the BG process
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR to perform asynchronous client/server processing.

You can also have a static class on the server which contains a static list of classes performing work regardless of client connection.